# Using the MongoDB Go Driver, how do I set up connection pooling?

Tags: mongodb, go, database-connection, connection-pooling

I'm using the [MongoDB Go Driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver) in my Go (1.11) server which runs on Google Cloud's App Engine. I'm not really sure if I still manually have to set up connection pooling or if it's already being taken care of out of the box. For example I'm not entirely sure what the context (with timeout) exactly means.

My code looks like this:

```golang
package tools

import (
    "context"
    "time"
    "valuation-app/settings"

    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
)

// ConnectToDB starts a new database connection and returns a reference to it
func ConnectToDB() (*mongo.Database, error) {
    settings := settings.Get().Database
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
    defer cancel()
    options := options.Client().ApplyURI(settings.URI)
    options.SetMaxPoolSize(10)
    client, err := mongo.Connect(ctx, options)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return client.Database(settings.DatabaseName), nil
}
```

Comment: The driver uses a connection pool internally.

Comment: @Adrian awesome! That's all I needed to know

Comment: in case you wonder where the [magics](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/blob/v1.0.3/x/network/connection/pool.go#L166) happen

Comment: @Adrian comment is correct ,default is 100 (from https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options#ClientOptions.SetMaxPoolSize)

Answer (score 7):

From comments by @Alongkorn:

[Mongo-go-driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver) takes care of connection pooling by default(100 connection by default)

You can read the source code [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/blob/v1.0.3/x/network/connection/pool.go#L166)